# Error Reading Multiple Excel Sheets Using openxlsx package in R

Tags: r, excel, export-to-excel

I'm trying to load an `Excel` workbook with a large number of tabs into `R`, do some analysis, and then export the results back into `Excel`. I'm using the `openxlsx package` because of some of the features of that package that are not easily accessible using other packages (such as the ability to create "`comments`" in the output file, `color code` the `tabs`, and work with `64-bit R`).

When I try to read in the workbooks, I sometimes get the following `error message` (or something similar):

```
Error in unzip(xlsxFile, exdir = xmlDir) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/MENDEL~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpIb3WOf/_excelXMLRead/xl/worksheets/sheet5.xml': Permission denied
```

This `error message` doesn't always show up - but sometimes it will appear and the program crashes.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this problem? I don't know why the program sometimes thinks it doesn't have permission to access the sheets.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible scenarios for this error:

**Scenario 1:**

C:/Users/MENDEL~1/AppData/Local/ (This looks like you are trying to read a temporary file)

**Solution:** 
If that is the case try moving the file to a different location like desktop and make sure that you update your working directory accordingly.

**Scenario 2**

C:/Users/MENDEL~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpIb3WOf/_excelXMLRead/xl/worksheets/**sheet5.xml**' (Looks like there is some issue with Sheet5 which is of type .xml and the openxlsx does not allow you to read .xml)

**Solution:**
Check if there is some issue with the format or contents of sheet5 in the file that you are trying to read.

[For additional information check CRAN Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf)

Comment: I have tried reading from my desktop too, and there's no difference.  Anyway, from the program's perspective, there should be no difference whether the file is saved in the Temp folder or anywhere else on the computer.  There is nothing wrong with Sheet5 (or any of the sheets).  When I just read sheet5 in, it works fine.  The bug happens when I try to read in a list of sheets in one go.  The program locks up in the middle.  I'm thinking this may be a bug with the package.

Comment: note that if I use the loadWorkbook() function, and then use read.xlsx on the workbook object created from that function, all sheets are read in with no problems.